# Why not appear on my Github profile contributions a commit after i copy my folder local and switch branch?

Tags: git, github

I make React project and save github.

I divide my project different bigger stage.

When i arrived an bigger stage i copy my local folder also and continue from that point.

I also copy my git folder but not copy node modules and package-lock.json ...etc because i'ts recreated after npm install

Now this point I can modify and save github no problem

But if I switch branch

```
 git checkout -b other-branch
 git push --set-upstream origin other-branch
```

Not showing my contributions on my profile?!

The changes appear on my correct branch  (other-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From github's FAQ:
[What counts as a contribution](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#what-counts-as-a-contribution):

> On your profile page, certain actions count as contributions:
>
> - Committing to a repository's default branch or gh-pages branch
> - Opening an issue
> - Opening a discussion
> - Answering a discussion
> - Proposing a pull request
> - Submitting a pull request review

So only commits to the default branch (`main`, `master`, `develop`, whatever) counts, `other-branch`  doesn't unless you define it as the default.

Comment: But why this? My lot of work "vanish"  from HR and employer so... I should commit all a single branch? What is the best practice? Thank you

Comment: If HR is concerned only by your contribution count, change employer not branch.